# Spring Boot JPA find, filter

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

As Spring jpa Provides some usefull features to find Items from a repository by defining it in the method name. e .x findByTitle(String title) then Spring is automatically searching the Title Colum for the given String. If i have an int column named numberOfCopies and i want only to find the datasets with >0 greater then null how would define such a method ?

to filter out those books with the numberOfCopies equals 0 = zero

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private int numberOfCopies;
}
```

can i use the Repomethod

public List findBooksByNumberOfCopies.greater then 0 ?To Use this Spring Feature without some if or for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use `Integer`, since it is better, in my opinion, to use wrapper classes than to primitives, and enforce `not null` requirement through annotations, e.g. `@Column(nullable = false)`

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private Integer numberOfCopies;
}
```

Then you can add the following two methods in your `BookRepository`;

```
List<Book> findByNumberOfCopiesGreaterThan(Integer numberOfCopies);

default List<Book> findAllAvailableBooks() {
    return findByNumberOfCopiesGreaterThan(0);
}
```

and use the `default findAllAvailableBooks` method, with hardcoded `0` value which is your requirement.

Comment: yes that worked! for what is this ? default List<Book> findAllAvailableBooks() {
    return findByNumberOfCopiesGreaterThan(0);
} It Is working with just List<Book> findByNumberOfCopiesGreaterThan(Integer numberOfCopies);

Comment: @MicroLova It is a trick to add zero in the method, you can insert `default` methods with some hardcoded values in repositories, with better method names `findAllAvailableBooks()` sounds much more readable than `findByNumberOfCopiesGreaterThan(0)` lol

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use

```
List<Book> findByNumberOfCopiesGreaterThanEqual(int numberOfCopies);
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.edis.demo.com.edis.demo.BookRepository.findByNumberOfCopiesGreaterThenEqual(int)! No property greaterThenEqual found for type int! Traversed path: Book.numberOfCopies

Comment: greaterTh__a__nEqual

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this would work:

```
public interface BookRepo extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {

   @Query("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.numberOfCopies >= 0")
   public Optional<List<Book>> getTheBooksWithMultCopies();

}

// back in your component class:
{
   ...
   Optional<List<Book>> optionalBookList = myBookRepo.getTheBooksWithMultCopies();
   if (optionalBookList.isPresent()){
      List<Book> bookList = optionalBookList.get();
   }
}
```

Note that the language within the query is called HQL, which is what is used by Hibernate internally (which is used by JPA internally). It's really not very intimidating - just, know that you the objects in your POJO, which map to your database table, rather than your database table directly.

Also, I'd recommend using Integer over int in entity classes, at least if your value is nullable. Otherwise, numberOfCopies will always default to 0, which may not be desirable and may cause exceptions that are difficult to decipher.

Comment: Worth noting, I also think Khaled Baklouti's answer works if you use Integer instead of int.

Answer (score 0):

GreaterThanEqual takes an `Integer` not `int`

```
List<Book> findByNumberOfCopiesGreaterThanEqual(Integer numberOfCopies);
```